# How to disable whatsapp open-url pop-up while scraping

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

I am currently working on a project where I have to scrape individual *WhatsApp* profile and get certain details from it using [api.whatsapp](https://wa.me/). With this link immediately the chrome browser pops up it displays a notification, which immediately stops all the code from running, I need to be able to bypass the pop up.

[image: The page looks like this]

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# location of web driver
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver'

# selecting what web browser to use
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(f'https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=%2B234{n}&text&type=phone_number&app_absent=0')
n = 88888888

try:
   element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
   EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Continue to Chat"))
)
except:
   driver.quit()
```

I tried using the **`WebDriverWait`** command thinking `id` be able to manually click cancel the *pop-up* tab and the code would continue.

Comment: I also tried using driver.switch_to.alert()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to skip alert open whatsapp frist

```
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
```

than use

```
js = """
            var [ num ] = [ arguments[0]];
            function openChat (t) {
                var e;
                t&&((e=document.createElement("a")).setAttribute("href","whatsapp://send?phone="+t),document.body.appendChild(e),e.click(),e.outerHTML="",setTimeout(1,1e3))
                
                      }
            return openChat(num)
        """
driver.execute_script(js, n)
```